# pytorch training loop ends with ''int' object has no attribute 'size' exception

Tags: python, pytorch

The code I am posting below is just a small part of the application:

```
def train(self, training_reviews, training_labels):
        
        # make sure out we have a matching number of reviews and labels
        assert(len(training_reviews) == len(training_labels))
        
        # Keep track of correct predictions to display accuracy during training 
        correct_so_far = 0
        
        # Remember when we started for printing time statistics
        start = time.time()
        
        
        criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        optimizer =  torch.optim.SGD(self.parameters(), lr=self.learning_rate)

        # loop through all the given reviews and run a forward and backward pass,
        # updating weights for every item
        for i in range(len(training_reviews)):
            
            # TODO: Get the next review and its correct label
            review = training_reviews[i]
            label = training_labels[i]
            print('processing item ',i)
            self.update_input_layer(review)
            output = self.forward(torch.from_numpy(self.layer_0).float()) 
            target = self.get_target_for_label(label)
            print('output ',output)
            print('target ',target)
            loss = criterion(output, target)

...
mlp = SentimentNetwork(reviews[:-1000],labels[:-1000], learning_rate=0.1)
mlp.train(reviews[:-1000],labels[:-1000])
```

and it ends with the exception in the title line when evaluating:

```
loss = criterion(output, target)
```

prior to that, the variables are as follows:

```
output  tensor([[0.5803]], grad_fn=<SigmoidBackward>)
target  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target should be a `torch.Tensor` variable. Use `torch.tensor([target])`.

Additionally, you may want to use batches (so there are `N` samples and shape of `torch.tensor` is `(N,)`, same for `target`).

Also see [introductory tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-beginner-blitz-cifar10-tutorial-py) about PyTorch, as you're not using batches, not running optimizer or not using `torch.utils.data.Dataset` and `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` as you probably should.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This code was not designed for pytorch, and it was not designed to use batches. So mine is some experimentation, I thought pytorch can also be used if the training loop scans one variable at a time, is this a valid assumption? BTW I fixed the issue reported before, but now I hit the next one ```Target 1 is out of bounds ``` at the same instruction.

Comment: @josephpareti Sure it can, but if you want to train you should probably change weights. Can't tell, I don't see your `criterion`.

Comment: i have specified ```criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()``` but I am not sure if this is correct since I only have one class with value ranging from 0 to 1

Comment: You should use `torch.nn.MSELoss` and output from the network should have `sigmoid` as an activation.